# Implement ASP.NET Core 6 Graceful Shutdown inside Kubernetes

Tags: asp.net, docker, kubernetes, azure-aks, asp.net-core-6.0

I need to implement Graceful Shutdown for my container(ASP.NET Core 6, runs on Alpine Linux). I have added below code.
When I run the container, it shows below log messages.

```
LifetimeEventsHostedService has been called.
StartAsync has been called.
OnStarted has been called.
```

But, when I send the "`kubectl delete pod my-pod-xyz -n mynamespace"` or restart the container, existing pod get terminated and start a new pod. But nothing shows on container log messages.

I expect to see the log message I have added to the **OnStopping** method, "OnStopping has been called". But nothing happens.

What could be the error? How can I ensure that my code is working properly when I restart or send the delete pod command?

**Program.cs**

```cs
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
                {
                    options.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(60);
                });
            }).ConfigureServices(services =>
            {
                services.AddHostedService<LifetimeEventsHostedService>();
                services.Configure<HostOptions>(option =>
                {
                    option.ShutdownTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);
                });
            });
}
```

**LifetimeEventsHostedService.cs**

```cs
internal class LifetimeEventsHostedService : IHostedService
{
    private readonly ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService> _logger;
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _appLifetime;

    public LifetimeEventsHostedService(
        ILogger<LifetimeEventsHostedService> logger,
        IHostApplicationLifetime appLifetime)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _appLifetime = appLifetime;
        _logger.LogInformation("LifetimeEventsHostedService has been called.");
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("StartAsync has been called.");
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(OnStarted);
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStopping.Register(OnStopping);
        _appLifetime.ApplicationStopped.Register(OnStopped);

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("StopAsync has been called.");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private void OnStarted()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnStarted has been called.");
    }

    private void OnStopping()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnStopping has been called.");

        _logger.LogInformation("SIGTERM received, waiting for 30 seconds");
        Thread.Sleep(30000);
        _logger.LogInformation("Termination delay complete, continuing stopping process");
    }

    private void OnStopped()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("OnStopped has been called.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @Bishan , I face the same problem, have you found a solution for it?

Comment: @UsemeAlehosaini Yes, I have added an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77712470/1029088). We need to add `preStop` hook as mentioned in my answer, and then we can handle the rest with LifetimeEventsHostedService.cs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
  lifecycle:
    preStop:
      exec:
        command:
          - /bin/sh
          - '-c'
          - >-
            PID=$(ps | grep dotnet | grep -v grep | awk '{print $1}') &&
            kill -SIGTERM $PID
```

This code is intended to gracefully shut down a .NET application running in a container by finding the process associated with the `dotnet` application and sending a termination signal (SIGTERM) to that process when Kubernetes decides to stop the container. This approach helps in handling ongoing requests or tasks before the container shuts down completely, ensuring a smoother exit without abruptly terminating processes.

Answer (score 0):

In a Kubernetes deployment, you can use the preStop hook to gracefully handle pod termination. This allows the pod to complete any ongoing requests before it is terminated. To use the preStop hook, you need to add the following configuration to your deployment YAML:

```
  containers:
  - name: your-container-name
    image: your-image:tag
    imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
    lifecycle:
      preStop:
        exec:
          command:
          - sh
          - -c
          - sleep 30
```

The preStop hook will ensure that the pod has 30 seconds to complete any ongoing requests before Kubernetes initiates the termination process. This helps to gracefully handle the pod shutdown, preventing any disruption to ongoing tasks.

Pre-requesite: Your docker should have sh or bash to execute the command and modify the command accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response Chandan. instead of hardcoded time (ex: 30 sec), can I use a metric(prometheus metric) and hold the termination process until my app complete all tasks?

Comment: Though I haven't tried it myself, I believe the deployment should use static values and will not be able to handling metrics from Prometheus.